pySerial communication with OBD2 usb interface
Can someone explain to me how to write code to read Diagnostic Trouble Codes from car using OBD2 USB interface?
for example, in Python using PID commands for OBD2 and maybe using older standard, because I want to know and compare both codes. I wonder how to communicate with older cars like BMW e38 728i where it is ISO9141-2 but there is no OBD2 interface so I have to use adapter, the same for Honda CR-V rd1 that has a 3-pin adapter.
Can you write a code example for me?
I used pySerial to write simple code:
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port="COM5", baudrate=921600, bytesize=8, timeout=1)
ser.write(b"0100\r\n")
time.sleep(3)
res = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)
print(res)
time.sleep(3)
ser.close()


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I mean how i can write this code using ELM327 1.5a usb interface with optional adatper for optional car to connect and send command to read DTCs. Can someone explain me how to read this command or code for example to start?
